# Upsert multiple records into salesforce with external ids

Tags: php, salesforce, upsert

I am upserting records using php tool kit into salesforce.
Salesforce have limit of 28000 inserts in a day. So to avoid this what i want to do is to insert 150 recors into one array and then inseet into salesforce. I this way 150 records will hit only once and i can upload more data into salesforce. Please help that who can i do it using php.

```
$this->SFLinks[$i] = new SObject();
$this->SFLinks[$i]->fields = array(
    'Name' => $fileName,
    'CanaryAMS' => $sfPolicyId,
    'Canary123AMS' => $url,
    'Description__c' => $description,
    'DocExternalId__c' => $documentKey
);
$this->SFLinks[$i]->type = 'CanaryAMS__Documents__c';
$checkreturn = $SforceConnection->upsert('CanaryAMS__DocExternalId__c',$this->SFLinks);
```

Comment: What do you mean by Upsert?

Comment: Upsert filename and urls for accountids

Comment: So your problem is how to insert at one shot?

Comment: Yes. I want to insert array of 150 records in one shot using upsert

Comment: Yes this is doable. You can concatenate your values you want to insert and then insert at one time. Recently have done in one of the project since there was a performance concern.

Comment: Can you please provide me some piece of code as i am using above code